# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null after push code

Tags: javascript

Error that show on console is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at app.post (/root/src/master.js:24:29)
```

master.js 24:29 is this

```
let outputs = req.body.outputs
  let outs = []
  for (let out of outputs) {
   outs.push({
     address: out.addresses[0],
      value: out.value
    })}
  }
```

line 24 is address: 
`out.addresses[0],`

request from this json

```
"outputs": [
{
"value": 10000,
"script": "a91402f42dce015def2fab0b1d6f7f6c742bae66e75e87",
"addresses": [
"31xdnmzVzmAQ5CaWxtiDr3jwCFfeUpHEb1"
],
"script_type": "pay-to-script-hash"
},
{
"value": 1020,
"script": "0014396ef6487043092385338ccfe9d327fb031975d6",
"addresses": null,
"script_type": "pay-to-witness-pubkey-hash"
}
]
```

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show us how your `outputs` look like.

Comment: `out.addresses` is very likely to be `null`... as stated in the error message. --> in the second output... `"addresses": null,`

Comment: Because of `"addresses": null,` in your JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addresses in null. You can add a null check

```
let outputs = req.body.outputs
let outs = []
for (let out of outputs) {
    outs.push({
      address: out.addresses ? out.addresses[0] : '',
      value: out.value
    })}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate!

Answer (score 0):

Since your `addresses` can be null (as per sample outputs you have shared),

```
for (let out of outputs) {
   outs.push({
     address: out.addresses ? out.addresses[0] : [], //notice the change here
      value: out.value
    })}
}
```

set an *empty array* if the `out.addresses` is `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your help mate!

Answer (score 0):

`address` is null at one place in object,

So, you can add a condition to check if `address` is `present` using a `terniary` operator.

```
let outputs = req.body.outputs
  let outs = []
  for (let out of outputs) {
   outs.push({
     address: out.addresses ? out.addresses[0] : '',
      value: out.value
    })}
  }
```

**`address: out.addresses ? out.addresses[0] : '',`**

`The above line checks if`out.addresses` is present and if yes it wll return that else return empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation ! Have a great day!

Comment: glad to help you. You can upvote my answer. If you find it useful. :-)